# First of Function in SSRS / show first row of each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

In my SSRS report, I have more than 500 pages. In the header section, I have used an textbox with expression First (Productname), where the productname is one of the column in my report.

How to display the First row productname of each page on that control? Now it will always display the first row productname of first page on all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ReportItems collection. Get the name of the cell that contains the text you want by clicking it and looking at the properties, assuming the name is myColumnCell then the expression in you header cell would be

```
=First(ReportItems!myColumnCell.Value)
```

Look here for more details if required.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder